# Range of values for colormap

Tags: matlab, range, colormap

I want to make a colormap including three ticklabels: Low, Intermediate and High. However, these labels should correspond to a range of values. Low = 0-50, Intermediate = 50-100 and High = 100 - maxvalue.
The code I have so far is written below, however it goes wrong when I want to define the Ticks. Could someone help me how to implement the ranges in to the ticks?

Thanks a lot!

```
figure, imshow(result);

[maxval] = max(result(:));
[minval] = min(result(:));

% red, yellow, green
cmap = [0 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 0 0];  
colormap(cmap);
h = colorbar;    
caxis([minval maxval]);

set(h, 'Ticks',[0:1:50, 50:1:100, 100:1:maxval])
set(h,'Ticklabels',{'Low','Intermediate','High'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than you colormap only having three values, you'll want to repeat each value in your colormap several times so that it covers the whole range.

Also, you have defined your ticks to be an array of *many* arrays (`0:1:50` creates an *array* of 50 values). Each value in the array used for the `'Tick'` property is a *separate tick*.

Instead of passing in arrays, you'll want to take the mean of each range and use *that* as the tick location.

Something like this should accomplish what you want.

```
crange = 0:maxval;
cmap = zeros(numel(crange), 3);

cmap(:,1) = crange >= 50;
cmap(:,2) = crange < 100;

colormap(cmap);

h = colorbar;
caxis([0 maxval]);

set(h, 'Ticks', [25 75 mean([100 maxval])], ...
       'TickLabels', {'Low', 'Intermediate', 'High'});
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This helps me a little. But what I actually want is to have the green bar range from 0-50, yellow 50-100 and red 100-maxval. Could you also help me to arrange this?

Comment: @Ommie if this worked for you, consider marking it as a solution